# gameplay on a sequences of board tiles when clicked

Tags: javascript

how can i create a  tiles of 4X4 image is a sort of gameplay sequence of rounds. and when a user click on the image the tile is closed, so user can not see a color,but when a user then select 2 tiles with the same color the image them disappear.. the tiles are considered to be over when all of the tiles are opened.? can you help?

Functions:

```
function f1() {
    document.getElementById('tile1').style.backgroundColor="red";
}

function f2() {
    document.getElementById('tile2').style.backgroundColor="blue";
}

function f3() {
    document.getElementById('tile3').style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}

function f4() { 
    document.getElementById('tile4').style.backgroundColor="green";
}

function determineWinner() {  
    for(i=0;1<4;i++) {    
        if(tiles1[i]==tiles2[i] || tile3[1]==tile4[i]) {
            winner=false;
        }
    }
 }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="main">
        <div onclick="f1();"id="tile1"></div>
        <div onclick="f2();"id="tile2"></div>
        <div onclick="f3();"id="tile3"></div>
        <div onclick="f4();"id="tile4"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Uh, have you tried to implement anything? Here on Stack you need to at least attempt and share code so folks can help. To throw you a bone, you're likely going to have multiple arrays with click listeners that execute methods that compare tile meta you are storing somewhere.Those will likely have listeners attached to them so you can update game state somewhere else.

Comment: function f2(){document.getElementById('tile2').style.backgroundColor="blue";}
//    function f3(){document.getElementById('tile3').style.backgroundColor="yellow";}
//    function f4(){document.getElementById('tile4').style.backgroundColor="green";}
//    
for(i=0;1<4;i++){
    
        if(tiles1[i]==tiles2[i] || tile3[1]==tile4[i]){
            winner=false

Comment: div id="main">
            <div onclick="f();" id="tile1"></div>
            <div onclick="f2();"id="tile2"></div>
            <div onclick="f3();"id="tile3"></div>
            <div onclick="f4();"id="tile4"></div>
        </div>

Comment: how can i create a functions that will help me click on each image and the tile is closed.but when user then select 2 tiles with same color then image disapear.help?

Comment: If you're creating random tiles and they need to be match for colors then you will need to randomly create the colors first and store them somewhere. Once someone clicks on one save that location and compare it to the second clicked item. If they are the same color then set both to something unclickable. If they aren't then flip them both over and reset your game state. Your code doesn't accomplish the basics here and Stack is not intended for solutions gathering.

Answer (score 0):

To what I could understand from your question, you are trying to build card match sort of game where we flip the cards to match with the previous one.

To achieve the same, I have built this sample:

HTML:

```
<div class="playground">
  <div id="pb1" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb2" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb3" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb4" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb5" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb6" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb7" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb8" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb9" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb10" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb11" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb12" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb13" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb14" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb15" class="playbox"></div>
  <div id="pb16" class="playbox"></div>
</div>
<button class="newgame">Start a New Game</button>
```

CSS:

```
.playground{
  width: 440px;
  height: 440px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
}
.playbox {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #999999;
   border: 1px solid white;
   margin: 2px;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .red {background: red;}
 .black {background: black;}
 .orange {background: orange;}
 .blue {background: blue;}
 .yellow {background: yellow;}
 .green {background: green;}
 .pink {background: pink;}
 .purple {background: purple;}
```

JavaScript:

```
 function shuffleArray(array) {
   for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
 }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var color_arry = ['black', 'orange', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'purple', 'black', 'orange', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'purple']; //Array of 8 pairs of colors
  var last_indx = 17; // Any number outside the array index limit 
  var even_click = 0; // To check if it is even (2nd/4th) click to be used to close the tiles.
  var total_clicks = 0; //To calculate the total clicks used.

  $('.newgame').click(function(){
    //Reset the game.
    $('.playbox').attr('class', 'playbox');
    shuffleArray(color_arry);
    last_indx = 17;
    even_click = 0;
  });

  $('.playbox').click(function(){
var indx = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(2)) - 1; //Box id starts with "pb1" while the array index from 0.
$(this).addClass(color_arry[indx]); //Add the color class to current element
    $(this).addClass('flipped'); //Add flipped class to identify how many tiles have flipped.
    //alert(last_indx + " - " + indx);
    if(last_indx != indx) { //Do not do any thing if current tile is clicked again.
      //alert(last_indx);
      if(last_indx != 17){
        if(color_arry[indx] != color_arry[last_indx]) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#pb' + (last_indx + 1).toString()).attr('class', 'playbox');
        $('#pb' + (indx + 1).toString()).attr('class', 'playbox');
        last_indx = even_click == 0 ? indx : 17;
        }, 200);
    }
    else {
        last_indx = 17;
      if($('.playbox.flipped').length == 16)
        alert('Congrats! You found all the matched in ' + total_clicks + ' clicks!!')
    }
    }
    else {
        last_indx = indx;
    }
    even_click = even_click == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    total_clicks += 1;
  }
});

  $('.newgame').click();
});
```

The JavaScript Function shuffleArray will shuffle the array passed to it. Now we are using this function to shuffle our color array when we start a new game.

On click on any of the tile will check the current index and last clicked index. and based on the comparison, it will assign the color class to the current tile (element).

Comment: thank you ! i run the code but the tables are not  clickable ?why ,?

Comment: can you help you check out the code above ?i can not click on the tiles?

Comment: I hope you're using jQuery as this code is written in jruby. If not, I will try and change it to JavaScript.

Comment: please try to change it to javascript , how can i use jquery ?

Comment: Okay. Meanwhile, you can try with jQuery by adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to `<head>` of your html code.

Comment: @ggbyte your question made no mention of ReactJS at all.  also, **show some patience**

Comment: i am  trying to build  default game of 4*4 ,card match sort of game where we flip the cards to match with the previous one, till the whole card matches one another . please how i can use react.js for this task?

Comment: Sorry @ggbyte . I am not familiar with ReactJS. Will try if I could build something on that note.